# Folland question 15(a) Prove that $\mu(E):=\sup\{\mu(F)\mid F\subset E,\ \mu(F)<\infty\}$ is semifinite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. I am trying to prove that:
$$\mu_0(E):=\sup\{\mu(F)\mid F\subset E,\ \mu(F)<\infty\}$$
is a semifinite measure. I have already proven that this is a measure, i.e., I only need to prove that the measure $\mu_0$ is semifinite. Although this is confusing because: let $X$ be any nonempty set, let $\mathcal{M}$ be any $\sigma-$algebra on $\mathcal{M}$, and define $\mu$ be an measure on the measurable space $(X,\mathcal{M})$:
$$\mu(E):= \begin{cases} 0 &E =\emptyset\\ \infty &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Then $\mu(X) =\infty$ (by assumption), but there is no measurable subset of $X$ of finite nonzero measure (the only measurable subset of finite measure is the empty set).

I thought that $\mu$ is a measure (although I don't because this is seemingly producing a contradiction with the question prompt in the Folland book) because: if $\{E_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}\subset \mathcal{M}$ are disjoint, then:
$$\mu\Bigl(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j\Bigr):= \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ every $E_j$ is empty }\\ \infty &\text{ there exists a nonempty $E_j$}
\end{cases}$$
(Note that part (b) of question 15. of Folland is answered in another post, I am asking about part (a). I finished part (b) already by the way.)

Comment: The semifinite part of the measure you propose is just the zero measure.

Comment: Ok yeah thanks. I think I might see it now. If $\mu_0(E) = \infty$, then $\infty$ is the supremum of the such $\mu(F)$'s which are all finite, meaning that at least one such $\mu(F)$ (and in fact, I think infinitely many) must be nonzero, no?

Comment: That's right; see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, observe that if $\mu (E) < \infty$ then we have $\mu (E) = \mu_0(E)$. Now, we just need to show that for $E \in \mathcal{M}$ with $\mu_0 (E) = \infty$ there is an $F \subset E$ such that $0 < \mu_0(F) < \infty$. But this follows immediately from: $$\mu_0(E) = \sup\{ \mu (F) \, : \, F \subset E, \, \mu (F) < \infty \} = \sup\{ \mu_0 (F) \, : \, F \subset E, \, \mu_0 (F) < \infty \}$$
Provided the second family is non-empty, then at least one set has positive finite $\mu_0$ measure.

Answer (score 2):

For the $\mu$ you gave, there are simply no measurable sets $E$ for which $\mu_0(E) = \infty$, so the condition of being semifinite is verified vacuously.

To prove $\mu_0$ is semifinite in general, if $\mu_0(E) = \infty$, then by the definition of supremum, for every $\alpha$, there is $F\subset E$ with $\alpha < \mu(F) < \infty$.